# Java Servlets, how to keep request attribute alive across several forwards?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets

I have a home-grown MVC implementation.  A ControllerServlet like so:

```
/controller?cmd=EditUser&userid=55
```

From this URL, the controller creates a `EditUserCommand.class` instance and calls an `execute()` method which returns the result page (ex. `user.jsp`) to display.

The controller servlet then does a ...

```
getRequestDispatcher(resultPage).forward(request, response);
```

... and the resulting page is shown.

One of the things the controller does is set messages (error, info, and so on) as request attribtues.  For example:

```
request.setAttribute("infoMessage", "User was edited successfully.");
```

And that message gets pulled out of the request in the `user.jsp` page and displayed.

Works fine.

Now here comes my problem.

Sometimes my commands don't return a page like `user.jsp` but return a URL like `cmd=ShowUser&userid=55` for the result.  This is because there might be things I want to check before displaying the final page, like permission to view the user and so on.

When I do this the "infoMessage" I placed in the request never appears because the result is a URL that makes a new call to the servlet, which is a new request.  The new request doesn't maintain the request attributes from the first request; which makes sense, I just didn't forsee this happening.

How can I make my request variable "stay alive" until it's actually displayed on the final page that results from the original request?

Any suggestions or advice are appreciated.  Just FYI, I can't re-write the entire app to go to something like Struts, Spring MVC, of JSF.  It's not an option.

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: One method may be append message to URL so that it will be available for next controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be giving a simple example, but your control flow causes the "Resend" Error, perhaps? Basically, after making any change to the data, the controller must immediately do a "Get" via a redirect and the screen should be displayed completely stateless.

Please take a look:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

As such, Attributes are not a great help. What you may want to consider is, maintaining a Bean/Object for every login user, and persist this object in a LRU cache (JCache or MemcacheD), and retrieve it on every entry to the application. Once you have that, you can maintain a pseudo-state such as previous results in that object.

In any case, using Attributes to retain state will severely constrain your options. You need to have a more generic flexible routing-independent mechanism.

Comment: Your "maintaining a Bean/Object" suggestion gave me my solution.  Friday afternoon success!  I created a Messages object that encapsulates all my messages, I keep the Messages object in the session and pass it into the command.execute(...) method.  It's good because every command (EditUser, then ShowUser, and so on) can add whatever messages they want.  Then JSP that eventually results removes the messages object out of the session, displays the messages.  Works great!  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. Great, but please think again about keeping that in the Session. That would cause you trouble when you implement load balancing. Think about using a remote store, like a cache server, or even a table in the database.

Answer (score 4):

`redirect` generally looses request data because of brand new request from browser. One possible approach may be append your message to url string as attribute and read it when you need.

Based on your EDIT: After your edit also, my answer make sense. But, only one correction is, it is not brand new request because forward happens on server side.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually doing a `forward`, not a redirect.  (I just fixed this in my question.)  The problem, I think, is because I'm forwarding to a new servlet request, not to a JSP.

Comment: Also, thanks for the "url string" suggestion, but that won't work because the messages can get complex, there's four different types and there can be multiple messages per type.  I need to set the object as a request attribute.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, even though you forward it to servlet, you can append the URL with message (or) you can add message to request parameter. When it is forward, request object will be still available.

Comment: @srini.venigalla, agree, but as said one way of handling.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a RequestDispatcher instead of a Redirect?

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/myNextPage.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Actually, sorry, yes -- I am actually doing the .forward like you suggest, not the sendRedirect I described.  I will fix that in the question.